# C Cmake setup - undefined reference to pow() (despite -lm)

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to build a project (with CLion) with the following `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(alfa_1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -lm")

set(SOURCE_FILES
        src/foo.h
        src/foo.c
        src/bar.h
        src/bar.c
        src/parser.h
        src/parser.c)

add_executable(alfa_1 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

In `foo.c` I use `pow()` function from `math.h`, which I include in `foo.h`. And obviously `foo.h` is included in `foo.c`. In `bar.c` I have `main` that is doing nothing. Now, standard command line compilation like this

```
gcc -o bar bar.c bar.h foo.h foo.c -lm
```

works fine but building the project yields undefined reference to `pow`. As one can see I included `-lm` flag in `CmakeLists.txt` file, so I don't get why this linking part is not working here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` are flags for the C++ compiler. `-l` is a linker flag. To link to a library, use this:

```
target_link_libraries(alfa_1 m)
```

You might also want to replace `-std=c11` with use of [`CMAKE_C_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_C_STANDARD.html) and related variables (`CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED`, `CMAKE_C_EXTENSIONS`), and possibly replace use of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` with a call to [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html).

Comment: It's important to mention than `target_link_libraries(alfa_1 m)` must be placed after the `add_executable(...` sentence, otherwise you will get an error like `Cannot specify link libraries for target "alfa_1" which is not built by the project`

Answer (score 0):

add the link of library in the cmakeList

```
add_library(math STATIC path/to/file.cpp)

add_executable(cmake_hello main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(cmake_hello math)
```

and in the class cpp

```
#include "path/to/file.hpp"
```

for mode detaills see this [link](https://medium.com/@onur.dundar1/cmake-tutorial-585dd180109b)

Answer (score 0):

In Clion this configuration solved my problem:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(K_Nearest C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(K_Nearest main.c point.h point.c group.c group.h)
target_link_libraries(K_Nearest m)
```

The important step was:     `target_link_libraries(K_Nearest m)`, it should come after `add_executable(...)` statement.